# Обновить, добавить элемент RecyclerView (Fragment) из Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Как передать значения из активности во фрагмент, не пересоздавая его?
Нужно добавить элемент:

Дата

```
    public class DialogList {
    public String name;
    public String age;
    public int photoId;

    public DialogList(String name, String age, int photoId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.photoId = photoId;
    }
}
```

Фрагмент

```
private List<DialogList> persons;

  public void addItems(String word) {
        persons.add(new DialogList(word, "35 years", R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground));
        rv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Активность

```
public void fragment(String agr){

   MyFragment catFragment = (MyFragment) 
        getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
    catFragment.addItems(agr);
}
```

Тут `addItems`горит красным

`xml` Активности

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout">

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Горит красным значит не видит такого метода у объекта у которого ты пытаешься его вызвать. getFragmentManager() возможно возвращает тебе объект Fragment, а у него такого метода нет. Попытайся сохранить ссылку на  MyFragment, когда ты его создаешь и у него вызывай этот метод.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал так  'com.app.Fragment.MyFragment' - Заработало